# Ionproduct of Water

Tags: acid-base, equilibrium

The ionproduct of pure water is well known to be
$$
K_{\rm W} = \left[ {\rm OH^-} \right] \left[ {\rm H_3O^+} \right] = 10^{-14}
$$
at some standard conditions (I think 25°C).

However having some acid HA in water as far as I'm aware this product is always the same i.e. $pK_{\rm a} + pK_{\rm b} = 14$.

How can this be derived?

Comment: I do not think this question is in any way answered there!
Equilibrium constants are defined for pure reactions, for instance
$$
{\rm H_2O + H_2O} \quad \substack{k_1 \\ \longrightarrow \\ \longleftarrow \\ k_2} \quad {\rm OH^- + H_3O^+}
$$
is such a pure reaction and then $K_{\rm W} = \frac{k_1 \left[{\rm H_2O}\right]^2}{k_2}$. However adding additional reactions of the form
$$
{\rm HA + H_2O} \quad \substack{\longrightarrow \\ \longleftarrow} \quad {\rm H_3O^+ + A^-}
$$
in principle changes the chemistry and thus also the equilibrium constant!

Comment: @Diger - You're sort of right but not in the way that your postulating. In reality it is the [activity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_coefficient) of H+ and OH- that are in equilibrium. In "dilute" solutions the activity is essentially the same as the concentration. However in more concentrated solutions the activity is less than the concentration.

Comment: @Diger - An "aqueous solution" should be about 1 kg per liter and have about 55 moles of water per liter for equilibriums like Ka and Ksp to work nicely.  (In other words, "dilute solutions.") As a poor example think of putting a drop of sulfuric acid in 100 ml water. That's fine. Now if you put a liter of sulfuric acid in 100 ml of water it isn't really an "aqueous solution" any more.

Comment: So in a general set of chemical reactions, does the equilibrium constant $K$ for one specific reaction change when I am adding further reactions to my system? In fact that is what I would expect.

Comment: For example consider the differential equation for $\ce{OH-}$ only of a dilute solution for the first reaction above in pure water
$$
\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t} \ce{[OH-]} = k_1 \ce{[H2O]^2} - k_2 \ce{[H3O+][OH-]}
$$
in equilibrium the derivative is zero and then you precisely get $K_{\rm W} = \frac{k_1 \left[{\rm H_2O}\right]^2}{k_2}$.

Comment: However if I now add the second equation to the system this equation changes to
$$
\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t} \left[ {\rm OH^-} \right] = k_{1} \left[ {\rm H_2O} \right]^2 + k_{\rm A^- + H_2O} \left[ {\rm H_2O} \right] \left[ {\rm A^-} \right] - \left\{ k_{\rm HA + OH^-} \left[ {\rm HA} \right] + k_{2} \left[ {\rm H_3O^+} \right] \right\} \left[{\rm OH^-}\right] \, .
$$
And then
$$
\ce{[OH-][H3O+]}=\frac{k_{1} \left[ {\rm H_2O} \right]^2 + k_{\rm A^- + H_2O} \left[ {\rm H_2O} \right] \left[ {\rm A^-} \right] - k_{\rm HA + OH^-} \left[ {\rm HA} \right]\left[ {\rm OH^-} \right]}{k_2} \,.
$$

Comment: Of course in general/principle I would have to solve the entire system i.e. with the additional reactions
$$
\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t} \left[ {\rm H_3O^+} \right] = k_{1} \left[ {\rm H_2O} \right]^2 + k_{\rm HA + H_2O} \left[ {\rm H_2O} \right] \left[ {\rm HA} \right] - \left\{ k_{\rm H_3O^+ + A^-} \left[ {\rm A^-} \right] + k_{2} \left[ {\rm OH^-} \right] \right\} \left[{\rm H_3O^+}\right]
$$

Comment: and
$$
\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t} \left[ {\rm A^-} \right] = -\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t} \left[ {\rm HA} \right] = \left\{ k_{\rm HA + H_2O} \left[ {\rm H_2O} \right] + k_{\rm HA + OH^-} \left[ {\rm OH^-} \right] \right\} \left[ {\rm HA} \right] - \left\{ k_{\rm A^- + H_2O} \left[ {\rm H_2O} \right] + k_{\rm H_3O^+ + A^-} \left[ {\rm H_3O^+} \right] \right\} \left[{\rm A^-}\right]
$$
and then create the product $\ce{[OH-][H3O+]}$ with the solutions of steady state, but I do not expect this product to be precisely $K_{\rm W}$.

Answer (score 1):

For some acid $\ce{HA}$, you have

$$\ce{HA + H2O <=> H3O+ + A-}$$

$$\ce{A- + H2O <=> OH- + HA}$$

We then define:

$$K_{\mathrm{a}} = \frac{\ce{[H3O+]\ce{[A-]}}}{\ce{[HA]}}$$

$$K_{\mathrm{b}} = \frac{\ce{[OH-]\ce{[HA]}}}{\ce{[A-]}}$$

Immediately, you see that $K_{\mathrm{a}}K_{\mathrm{b}}=K_{\mathrm{w}}$.

Now, if you take the negative log of both sides:

$$-\log\left(K_{\mathrm{a}}K_{\mathrm{b}}\right)=-\log K_{\mathrm{w}}$$
$$=\mathrm{p}K_{\mathrm{a}}+ \mathrm{p}K_{\mathrm{b}} = 14$$

The 14 comes from the value of $K_{\mathrm{w}}$.

Comment: I guess the problem I have with this is the way how to view it.
Say you start with very little $\ce{HA}$ so that $\ce{[A-]}$ is very small and the equilibrium hardly deviates from $\ce{[OH-]}=10^{-7}$ and $\ce{[H3O+]}=10^{-7}$. In this case you are right about the product being $K_{\rm W}$. Now you continuously increase the acid $\ce{HA}$ while both $\ce{[OH-]}$ and $\ce{[H3O+]}$ individually change their values. Is it because of $K_a K_b$ being a constant only dependent on temperature and also due to continuity, that this cannot change while the acid concentration is changed over magnitudes?

Comment: Another point worth mentioning which I'm not sure about is that: Aren't $K_a$ and $K_b$ by itsself so by each reaction above alone defined as I noted in the other comment? Do these values not changed upon mutual influence in the reaction?

Comment: Or put it another way: Does the value of $K$ not changed in equilibrium, regardless of how many reactions I might add to the chemistry which certainly will affect it.